# Enhancing Audio Trimmer Widget in Flutter App

Tags: flutter, audio, editor, trim, flutter-audioplayers

I'm in the process of developing an Audio Trimmer app using Flutter and currently utilizing the easy_audio_trimmer package. However, I find the default Audio Trim Widget provided by this package unsatisfactory for my application. Instead, I aspire to design my app's interface to resemble the layout depicted in the image below:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fx09x.jpg)

I'm seeking guidance on how to achieve this customized interface for my Flutter app. Any insights or alternative packages that offer similar functionalities with a more customizable widget would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!